# How to cancel an article submission

Tags: publications

I submitted an article to a journal that is now under consideration after revisions.
Some potential authors I didn't mention in this article censure the submission. To stay on good terms with them I would like to cancel the submission. The article is not already accepted but I think it will be in few days.
What can I do?

Comment: What is a potential author? Someone who should have been an author and you somehow "forgot" to add them?

Comment: I think that this question cannot be correctly answered unless we understand more about the situation: if the other investigators have a reasonable case, then withdrawing the article may be correct.  It may also be appropriate to change the author list rather than withdrawing.  It may also be bullying that should be resisted.  Can you please edit the question to provide more details?

Answer (score 6):

Contact the editor of the journal immediately and tell them you wish to withdraw the article.